# Keeping 'client_secret' hidden in source code on a frontend app without backend

Tags: github, oauth, frontend

I am currently building a pure frontend app without a backend that will be open-source on Github, that use the Github OAuth to grant permission to use the ability of creating gists on behalf of the user. I follow the [official doc from Github](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorization-options-for-oauth-apps/).

The problem is that I need to send the *'client_secret'* of the app to grant the authorisation. But how can I send it without writing it in plain text in the source code?

Comment: You can't. If you need it in your front-end code users will be able to access it no matter what you try. One common (but painful) strategy is to require each of your users to register their own OAuth application and use their own client secret, which they would enter using whatever configuration interface you provide. (Note that this has nothing to do with making your application open source on GitHub. It's just the way front-end code works.)

Comment: Ok this is what I thought... I was previously using anonymous gist API, which didn't need to register an app and using *'client_id'* and *client_secret* but Github [deprecated it](https://blog.github.com/2018-02-18-deprecation-notice-removing-anonymous-gist-creation/). Thank you for your answer.